# PHP cURL with cookie to POST/Submit jQuery form and get result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl, cookies

Im working on a php cURL with Cookie to Submit a jQuery/Java form and receive results.

I want this script to:

- Visit https://unlock.telstra.com/iphoneunlock/main
- Enter IMEI: 013064001494963
- Submit Form
- Receive the result from FORM page

> So far with my script below I'm able to:

1) Visit the URL and SAVE Cookie to file.

```
<?php 

$get_cookie_page = 'https://unlock.telstra.com/iphoneunlock/main';
echo curl_download($get_cookie_page);

function curl_download($Url){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
  $http_headers = array(
                    'Host: unlock.telstra.com',
                    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2',
                    'Accept: /*',
                    'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5',
                    'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
                    'Connection: keep-alive'
                  );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

  $output = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);
  return $output;
}

?>
```

2) Use the Cookie and get FORM

```
<?php

$imei = '013064001494963';
$submit = 'Submit';
$fields = array(
        "imei" => $imei,
        "_eventId_submit" => $submit
);

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');    

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://unlock.telstra.com/iphoneunlock/main?execution=e1s1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
$http_headers = array(
                    'Host: unlock.telstra.com',
                    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2',
                    'Accept: /*',
                    'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5',
                    'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
                    'Connection: keep-alive'
                  );
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);      
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);  

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

var_dump($info);
var_dump($output);

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

As you see in the code above I added **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS** but on the result I get the FORM is empty.

Any suggestions on how to paste the values in this form and get results?

Here is the FORM:

```
<form id="unlockForm" class="form wide" action="/iphoneunlock/main?execution=e1s1" method="post">
    <input type="text" pattern="\d*" name="imei" id="imei-details" maxlength="15"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="4" name="_eventId_submit" class="btn" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="submit" id="cancel" tabindex="4" name="cancel" class="btn" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
```

Any advice? Thank you for helping.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's my work firewall or not but I can't access the site. It's unlikely the the response from the POST would give you anything terribly useful. What you need to do next depends on what happens after the form is submitted, what does the site do?

Comment: @davids: This FORM returns 5 type of results depending on the IMEI number you enter. 1) If iPhone is SIM locked to Telstra Australia then it will unlock for free. 2) If iPhone is SIM locked to other network then it will tell its SIM locked. 3) If iPhone is unlocked then it will tell its unlocked. 4) If iPhone have recently been unlocked then it will show other result like: sync iPhone with iTunes to complete unlock process. 5) Some iPhones can't be checked then it will show result like: If your mobile device is not an iPhone. - This FORM is connect to Apple GSX server and tells SIM lock status